# How to determine key in a piece of Chinese folk music

Tags: folk, numbered-notation

When viewing a piece of music that is notated like this, how does one determine the key?  A student sung it to me, and I was able to figure out that the numbers correspond to the scale degrees in a major scale.  The numbers without dots above them are in the lower octave.  In other pieces of music (all were notated like this) some notes have 2 dots above them which seem to indicate belonging to the octave above.

[image]

The student is from China, and speaks almost no English so I had to guess and couldn't ask.  I assume this is some kind of Chinese folk music.

Are my guesses correct, and how do I determine what key I should be in?  I started in C for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Could be some sort of NNS - CNS.

Comment: What are NNS and CNS?

Comment: Nashville Number System, thus Chinese Number System!

Comment: Last I knew the NNS was for chords, but this seems to be melody notes.

Comment: It'd still work for notes, though, wouldn't it. Just like NNS, for any key?

Comment: As Tim suggested, if it's notated using scale degrees, then it could be pitched in *any* key. I tried putting the image into Google Translate but I think I'm only getting lyrics—"orange sunset, engulfed... night slowly push away... show a little bit of starlight..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation system, *jiǎnpǔ* ("simplified notation"), is commonly used in China. As stated, the numbers correspond to degrees of the major scale. Wikipedia has a [full explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbered_musical_notation) of the system.

Since the system only states scale degrees, it can be performed in any key that fits the range of the instrument used.